# GetRandomRgn() Api does not work as expected in Windows 8

Tags: winapi, windows-8

I am using GetRandomRgn() API to get the visible region of the window.

This API works fine in Windows Xp and Windows 7 but same API is not giving the same

result in Windows 8.

Is there is any other function available in windows 8 to give me the same result?

Please do reply.

Best Regards,

Sharad

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "works fine" and "not giving the same result". What result do you get and why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Hi Raymond... GetRandomRgn() function copies the system clipping region of a specified device context to the specific region. That means the region which is visible is get clipped and get copied in to HRGN parameter.Suppose there is a App window and other window is coming top on some part of that App window, than GetRandomRgn() fucn should return the clipped rgn value for the visible part of the App window.In Windows Xp,Windows7 it is giving the correct clipped rgn value, but in Windows8 not giving the correct clipped rgn. It is not identifying that other window is coming on top of App Window.

Answer (score 2):

Enable Desktop Composition on Windows 7 and you'll see that Windows 7 and Windows 8 behave the same. The behavior of GetRandomRgn is affected by desktop composition. When composition is enabled, all windows are logically treated as fully visible (since they render to an offscreen buffer). The available of features like Flip3D shows that the logically visible portion of a region is not the same as its physically visible region.

Comment: Even Desktop Composition on Windows 7 is enabled GetRandomRgn is giving me the correct clipped region. It is not same what we are seeing in Windows 8.